# Setting 'xml:space' to 'preserve' Python lxml

Tags: python, xml, svg, lxml

I have a text element within an SVG file that I'm generating using `lxml`. I want to preserve whitespace in this element. I create the text element and then attempt to `.set()` the `xml:space` to `preserve` but nothing I try seems to work. I'm probably missing something conceptually. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by explicitly specifying the namespace URI associated with the special `xml:` prefix (see http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace).

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element("root")
root.set("{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}space", "preserve")

print etree.tostring(root)
```

Output:

```
<root xml:space="preserve"/>
```